# SQLite Update table

Tags: c++, sqlite

Trying to update table by user specified values. But the values are not getting updated.

```
cout<<"\nEnter Ac No"<<endl;
        cin>>ac;
        cout<<"\nEnter Amount"<<endl;
        cin>>amt;

        /* Create merged SQL statement */
        sql = "UPDATE RECORDS set BAL = '%d' where ACCOUNT_NO = '%d'",amt, ac;

        /* Execute SQL statement */
        rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, (void*)data, &zErrMsg);
```

If I replace BAL and ACCOUNT_NO by some integer value instead of place holder then it is working fine.

Comment: What are you expecting `sql = "UPDATE RECORDS set BAL = '%d' where ACCOUNT_NO = '%d'",amt, ac;` to do? Whatever it is, it  won't do it. C++ has no built-in string formatting.

Comment: Why do you expect `"UPDATE RECORDS set BAL = '%d' where ACCOUNT_NO = '%d'",amt, ac` to work at all? Do some research on prepared statements and bound parameters.

Comment: I want to update the balance of a particular customer both will be  given by the user into the table RECORD by using c++ @NeilButterworth

Answer (score 0):

Your sql string is not being created properly.

If you expect this code 
`sql = "UPDATE RECORDS set BAL = '%d' where ACCOUNT_NO = '%d'",amt, ac;`
to result in
`"UPDATE RECORDS set BAL = '1' where ACCOUNT_NO = '2'"`
where 
amt= 1 and ac = 2 then you need to use a string formatting call like this.

```
 // the buffer where your sql statement will live
char sql[1024];
 // write the SQL statment with values into the buffer
_snprintf(sql,sizeof(sql)-1, "UPDATE RECORDS set BAL = '%d' where ACCOUNT_NO = '%d'",amt, ac);
buff[sizeof(sql)-1]='\0';
```

On your particular platform `_snprintf(...)` might be `snprintf(..)` or another similarly named function. Also your compiler may warn about buffer manipulation security vulnerabilities. Choose the appropriate substitute for your needs

Comment: -1 for using C instead of C++, using non-standard functionality, a fixed-size buffer and worst of all, no prepared statements. This is how SQL injections are made possible.

Comment: So there's no value here then to help the questioner?

Comment: Sorry to be so harsh, but you do *not* help the questioner by posting bad code. In addition to that, helping the questioner is not the only goal of Stack Overflow. Remember: The purpose of this site is to create a huge **high-quality** knowledge base for programming problems.

Comment: For the OP: Please read https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: @Christian : So you're too busy to write a better answer then?

Comment: No, I voted to close the question because it's off-topic (no MCVE).